# Informatica: Data in column looks like 00003242-2-0-1,00000925-1-0-1,00003214-2-0-1 .In target I need data like 3242, 0925, 3214 in different rows

Tags: mapping, transformation, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Data in one column looks like this

```
00003242-2-0-1,
00000925-1-0-1,
00003214-2-0-1.
```

In target I need to get only data like

```
3242, 
0925, 
3214
```

in different rows. How can I achieve this using informatica mapping?

Comment: What’s the actual logic you are using - is it extracting the 4 characters before the first dash in each field?

Comment: I need the logic to apply in informatica mapping

Comment: That doesn't answer my question - I was asking you to define what the rules were to convert the source data to the target data. At the moment you've only provided the source and target values and are expecting someone to guess what the rules are (and that the sample data you've provided covers all possible scenarios)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a SUBSTR function in an Expression transformation